# generate new terminal (any) window from a script

Tags: bash, terminal

I would like to run a script that detects the current terminal and generates a new terminal window, in the background, with a shell command (e.g. `htop`)

I get the desired outcome at the command line:

```
cterminal="$(ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) o args=)"  
$(echo $cterminal -e "htop")&
```

and works on all terminals. But not from a script:

```
#!/bin/bash  
cterminal="$(ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) o args=)"  
echo $cterminal  
"$cterminal" -e "htop" &
```

current script output:

```
$ bash script.sh
/bin/bash  
$ /usr/bin/htop: /usr/bin/htop: cannot execute binary file
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ps` command is printing the PID of the parent process (PPID). When you are running a terminal emulator, `$$` (the current process's PID) will be pointing to your shell session and its PPID will be the terminal emulator that launched it.

Scripts are run in their own [subshells](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/What_is_a_Subshell%3F). This means that the parent process of a script is the shell that launched it. So, when you run your command, you are not executing `xterm -e htop` but `bash xterm -e htop`. To illustrate:

```
$ bash top  
/sbin/top: /sbin/top: cannot execute binary file
```

You can test this by running `echo $(echo $cterminal -e "htop")` from a script and from the commandline.

To run the script from a GUI terminal emulator, you could use the PPID's PPID instead:

```
cterminal="$(ps -p $(ps -p $PPID -o ppid=) o args=)"
```

Finally, don't use `$(echo ...)` to run your command, just run it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
$(ps -p $(ps -p $PPID -o ppid=) o args=) -e top
```

Comment: this makes a lot of assumptions about the environment - particularly about a bash's granddaddy necessarily being a terminal emulator. there's also the IFS/glob deal where *just running* it is concerned.